# Understanding the mean function for time series analysis

Tags: calculus, probability, expected-value

I am studying time series and came across the Mean function which the textbook defines as:
$$ \mu_{xt}=E(X_t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_t(x)dx  $$
I don't understand what this function does. I looked at the [Mean of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function) page but the formula looks different
$$ \bar{f}={\frac  {1}{b-a}}\int _{a}^{b}f(x)dx $$
Are these two functions the same?

What is the intuition of the Mean function and why is is important to know the mean of a time series function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the mean of the function, this is the expected value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of $X_t$. Think of it as the weighted average of $X_t$, where $f_t$ are the weights.

Comment: The textbook definitely calls it the Mean function. Could you provide further explanation on the Expected value?

Comment: Because it serves as the weighted average or weighted mean of the random variable. What else do you want to know about it?